# How to I print the number of jobs scheduled by scikit learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, parallel-processing, joblib

I plan to run the following code on AWS

```
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
pw_distance = pairwise_distances(model_in, model_out, n_jobs=-1)
```

How do I print the number of jobs scheduled with `n_jobs=-1`?
I'm aware that I can check monitor CPU usage with AWS but I also would like a direct readout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
from joblib import effective_n_jobs
print(effective_n_jobs(-1))
```

`pairwise_distances` uses [Parallel](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b3ea3ed6a/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py#L1364) under the hood; you can test it if you like:

```
from time import sleep
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
Parallel(n_jobs=-1, verbose=10)(delayed(sleep)(.2) for _ in range(10))
```

Output:

```
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 12 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   3 out of  10 | elapsed:    0.6s remaining:    1.3s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   5 out of  10 | elapsed:    0.6s remaining:    0.6s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   7 out of  10 | elapsed:    0.6s remaining:    0.3s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  10 out of  10 | elapsed:    0.6s finished
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry if this is a bit of an obvious question but if I use `print(effective_n_jobs(-1))` in the line after the `pairwise_distance` , wouldn't it give 1 as the pairwise distance parallelisation would have finished? Or am I misunderstanding the use of `effective_n_jobs`.

Comment: `print(effective_n_jobs(-1))` counts how many CPUs you have. The [Parallel documentation](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/blob/master/joblib/parallel.py#L425) states that "If n_jobs=-1 all CPUs are used". So if you set `n_jobs` to `-1`, all CPUs returned by `print(effective_n_jobs(-1))` will be used when you run `pairwise_distances `. If you want to print the number of CPUs _while `pairwise_distances` is running_, you would have to modify the source code of `pairwise_distances` or that of  `Parallel`.

Comment: Ohh I see, we're calling the same function used to dictate `pairwise_distances`. Thanks for the solution and explanation!